# Cancel an HTTP request when someone else call same method

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using angular, ngrx and rxjs in my application.
When an effect is called twice, the first effect http request is canceled, and only the second one is counted.

I want to emulate this in a function that is outside ngrx scope.

I have the following method :

```
checkMissionPoint(
    positions: Array<Cesium.Cartographic>
  ): Observable<{
    valid: boolean;
    response: Array<CheckWaypointResponse>;
  }> {

    return this.store$.pipe(
      select(TransactionsStoreSelectors.selectedTransactionId),
      take(1),
      switchMap((tId) =>
        this.httpClient
          .post<Array<CheckWaypointResponse>>(
            HTTPUtils.getPath(`${environment.FLIGHT_URL}/trajectories/${tId}/checkpoints`),
            {positions}
          )
          .pipe(
            switchMap((result) => {
              return result;
            })
          )
      )
    );
  }
```

I call this method like this in my app in various place in the application

```
    this.missionHelperService.checkMissionPoint(positions)
```

Now, I know some ugly way to cancel it, by keeping like a reference and unsubscribing if the method is called again and the reference still exist. But I am wondering if there is a nice rxjs way to achieve this.

Thanks.

EDIT : I made a small stackblitz but you need to setup SLOW 3G connection in your chrome console https://angular-xm2ixt.stackblitz.io

you will notice that the obs is called twice, the api will both fire and answer, what I want is the second call cancel the first (and dispatch an error to who was listening, and sub 2 will go trought has normal)

Comment: I am a little confused at what you are asking. Are you saying the code you posted is working? You just want the same functionality without rxjs?

Comment: Could you please provide a stackblitz demo? This would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar situation, this is how i solved it.

```
checkMissionPointCalled = new EventEmitter<void>();

checkMissionPoint(
    positions: Array<Cesium.Cartographic>
): Observable<{
    valid: boolean;
    response: Array<CheckWaypointResponse>;
}> {
    this.checkMissionPointCalled.emit();
    return this.store$.pipe(
        select(TransactionsStoreSelectors.selectedTransactionId),
        take(1),
        switchMap((tId) =>
            this.httpClient
                .post<Array<CheckWaypointResponse>>(
                     HTTPUtils.getPath(`${environment.FLIGHT_URL}/trajectories/${tId}/checkpoints`),
                        { positions }
                )
         ),
        takeUntil(this.checkMissionPointCalled)
    );
}
```

However, i was not able to get the use of

```
         .pipe(
            switchMap((result) => {
              return result;
            })
          )
```

after `httpClient.post` call, i think probably this was an error. So, haven't included it in my answer.

You will probably also want to close `checkMissionPointCalled` in `ngOnDestroy` method.

Comment: I thank I will check, The use of that is because in my real app I do some manipulation there, so I included a simple function to show that I am doing something there.

Comment: your solution works indeed, I think it s not the best rxjs wise, but it does the trick thanks. and since nobody else respond here...

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have now, is that the `checkMissionPoint()` method returns a brand new observable for every caller.

I think you could achieve what your are trying to do if you had a private observable and returned that same observable to all callers.  This observable would use `switchMap()` to achieve the cancelling behavior you are looking for.

```
private positions$ = new Subject();
private uri$ = this.store$.pipe(
    select(TransactionsStoreSelectors.selectedTransactionId),
    map(tId => HTTPUtils.getPath(`${environment.FLIGHT_URL}/trajectories/${tId}/checkpoints`)
);
private checkMissionPoint$ = combineLatest([this.uri$, this.positions$]).pipe(
    switchMap(([uri, positions]) => this.httpClient.post<CheckWaypointResponse[]>(uri, {positions}))
);

checkMissionPoint(
    positions: Array<Cesium.Cartographic>
  ): Observable<{
    valid: boolean;
    response: Array<CheckWaypointResponse>;
  }> {
    this.positions.next(positions);

    return this.checkMissionPoint$.pipe(
      take(1)
    );
}
```

Depending on your use case, it may be cleaner to have the method return `void` and make the common observable public:

```
private positions$ = new Subject();
private uri$ = this.store$.pipe(
    select(TransactionsStoreSelectors.selectedTransactionId),
    map(tId => HTTPUtils.getPath(`${environment.FLIGHT_URL}/trajectories/${tId}/checkpoints`)
);
public missionPoint$ = combineLatest([this.uri$, this.positions$]).pipe(
    switchMap(([uri, positions]) => this.httpClient.post<CheckWaypointResponse[]>(uri, {positions}))
);

setPosition(
    positions: Array<Cesium.Cartographic>
  ): Observable<{
    valid: boolean;
    response: Array<CheckWaypointResponse>;
  }> {
    this.positions.next(positions);
}
```

Comment: your answer contain mistake and typos, but it solve the issue. thanks.

Comment: I tried the first solution cause it fit better my usecase, it does cancel, but it create more api call with the latest parameters.

like I call 1 time, cancel, the next call will create 2 api call with same parameters, then cancel, the 3 will make 3 etc... I think the cancel call should return an error or something.

Comment: `switchMap` will cancel current in-flight API calls when a new one comes in. `exhaustMap` will ignore new requests until the current one is done.

Comment: @MrkSef `switchMap` is what I want, and what is in the answer, the problem, it does cancel the API, but it calls multiple instead of a single one. But if there is no problem in the answer, then it might be in my code ?